# why do i get an error when i import psycopg2

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2, uvicorn

i install psycopg2 and when i import it in python its saying

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2'

i followed a tutorial online and i followed exactly what the guy did and for some reason it is not working

i did pip install psycopg2

it installed good then when i imported it in python with

```
import psycopg2
```

i get the error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2'

Comment: You have two (or more) versions of Python installed on your system.  `pip` installed the psycopg2 module for one version, but you're using a different version to run your code, and that version does not have the module installed.

Comment: An alternate explanation to @JohnGordon comment, you are using `virtualenv`'s and installed `psycopg2` either system wide and are now working in a `virtualenv` that does not see it or the other way around. Or you installed in one `virtualenv` and are now working in another one that does not have `psycopg2` installed.

Comment: @JohnGordon i updated my pip then it started working, thank you